# In Emacs, how can I see which slime version is being used?

Tags: emacs, slime, elpa

I just upgraded my slime using elpa in Emacs. But I wonder if things are like they should be now, because when I removed the old version using elpa, it complained it could not remove a certain folder. So, when I start up Emacs (I know, I shouldn't have closed it), how I can see which slime version actually gets used? Is there a command like M-x slime-version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **no slime releases**, just CVS snapshot. Use

```
(slime-changelog-date)
```

to get the latest changelog/commit date.

Comment: Great, tnx. Whenever I do this, while not being connected to a swank server, it says: not connected. Why do I actually have to be connected in order to see the slime version?

Comment: You don't have to be connected. But most likely slime is autoloaded on you system:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Autoload.html

so you need to (require 'slime)

Answer (score 2):

When you start a REPL with the M-x slime command, the SLIME version is shown on the first line of the REPL, like:

> ; SLIME 20100404

Btw you can always go to your elpa folder(the one in which elpa installs the packages) and remove the problematic folder by hand.